# Powershell Parsing Help - Intermediate-sortaIntermediate Question

Tags: arrays, parsing, text, powershell, split

I have a text file with the following format:

```
Rtmp: 2a1234bzcde9 SL ID: 1549566 IP: 192.168.0.1
Rtmp: 45a1234b4erde9 SL ID: 1549566 IP: 192.168.0.1
Rtmp: a1254bcde9 SL ID: 1549566 IP: 192.168.0.1
Rtmp: 23a1ft4bcde9 SL ID: 1549566 IP: 192.168.0.1
Rtmp: a125egbcde9 SL ID: 1549566 IP: 192.168.0.1
```

I have several hundred entries involved here.

The problem is that I need to get the second entry in each line of text (inbetween rtmp and sl).  Each of those numbers has a length between 6 to 15 characters, all random characters.

How would I pull it into an array of those numbers?  I want to use these numbers to make them the names of user accounts in 2008r2 (not using AD) and create folders in the inetpub/ftproot and create the folders in there with aliases and link each account to its corresponding virtual folder.

The last bit I can do.. it's manipulating text files that I suck at!!  Here's what I've got so far:

```
$items = Get-Content $HOME/desktop/info.txt

$splitItems = @()
$splitItems = foreach ($item in $items)
{
    $item.split(" ")
}
```

That splits each line, so that splitItems[0] is the first line of text, now split into multiple lines of text because of the space delimiter.

If I tried to take the SplitItems aray and use the same type of foreach to further split it.  It gave me back an array of chars.  USEFUL LOL haha.  well.. each way I try I keep getting mumbo jumbo or it's not a string type (though get type seems to say it's a string).  I think in the process the string type changes to a generic io.object type?

Any ideas or help would be immensely appreciated.!!!

Answer (score 3):

The regex answers may be the right way to go, but if your input file is really as consistently formatted as you suggest, you may have been on the right track to begin with.  Try something like this:

```
$accounts = gc info.txt | % { ($_ -split ' ')[1] }
$accounts
```

Comment: Yes it is very reliable.  Thank you for your input!! Well ok so that splits it, then how can I get the value I want?  

One of my goals in posting this question was to learn more about Regex because I don't seem to be able to find a simple thing to explain the syntax.  

So could I do $accounts[2] and somehow take the amount of entries in the array and get every $account[$count] and have the count start at 2 and increase the count at the end of every foreach loop?

Comment: Did you try the commands above with the sample data you provided? If so, you should see that the variable $accounts is an array of 5 elements, each of which is the second field on the corresponding input line.  Since indexes are zero-based, $accounts[2] would be 'a1254bcde9'.

Answer (score 2):

Given your text file is "c:\temp\t.txt", can you test this :

```
switch -regex -file "c:\temp\t.txt"
{
  "^Rtmp: (.*) SL.*$" {$matches[1]}  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = "Rtmp: 2a1234bzcde9 SL ID: 1549566 IP: 192.168.0.1 Rtmp: 45a1234b4erde9 SL ID: 1549566 IP: 192.168.0.1 Rtmp: a1254bcde9 SL ID: 1549566 IP: 192.168.0.1 Rtmp: 23a1ft4bcde9 SL ID: 1549566 IP: 192.168.0.1 Rtmp: a125egbcde9 SL ID: 1549566 IP: 192.168.0.1"

[regex]$regex = "Rtmp:\s(\S+)\sSL"
[regex]::matches($a,$regex) | foreach-object {$_.groups[1].value}

2a1234bzcde9
45a1234b4erde9
a1254bcde9
23a1ft4bcde9
a125egbcde9
```

Comment: Just realized from the description your file probably has line breaks that aren't in the test data. You can use this to read all the data as a single line: $a = (new-object system.io.streamreader $HOME/desktop/info.txt).readtoend()

Comment: Thank you so much this is what I was hoping for .. I want to learn more about regex with your well written example.  

So you create a variable, type regex (from dot net right?) and you call the 'matches' method? And the first argument is the array with data, and the second is the argument to pull that 'sub string' out?

What does the (\S+) mean?  I can tell you're like sandwiching it .. I see what you're doing but do not know what it is .. if you could explain a bit or point me to a resource where I can learn more about Regex especially in Powershell I would be SO HAPPY!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract one part from a string, and this string is following a defined pattern, simply use '-replace' and a [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=VS.85).aspx).

```
$numbers = ($items -replace '^Rtmp: (\S+) SL.*$','$1')
```

This line will iterate through each item, extract the string and output it to the new array.

Some meanings:

- *\S+* means "One or more characters that are not whitespace"
- *$1* means "The part within the first set of brackets"

Comment: Wait so what part is in the brackets?  Thank you for your input my friend!  

Also please i'm dying to know .. what is (\S+) ? What is the \s and what does the + do to it?  I saw another person respond where he used a white space deally I'm assuming \s by itself.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx is probably a decent place to start for a description of .Net regular expression elements.